# Swiping item in recyclerview will display additional content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that contains imageview as item. Im expecting when swiping an item, the item detailed information will be displayed on that row. If released, the row will return to the way it was. Should I use fragment for this. If so, what should I do? I just started learning about fragments.